# Importing Excel sheet to MySQL on MAC OS X 10.10.2

Tags: mysql, mysql-workbench, mysql-error-1064

I am trying to import excel sheets to MySQL on MAC OS X . But I couldn't able to do that . When I have selected Data Import/Restore , I could able to select excel sheet (.csv) , it is grey out basically .

Can anyone explain me steps for importing excel sheets on MAC OS X

Answer (score 1):

There is a free version of a third party tool named as Excel2MySQL that does this job pretty well. Did you give it a try?

URL: http://excel2mysql.net/compare.html

Comment: hey ! I tried it , but it is confined to Windows I believe

Comment: My question still unfolded . Can someone explain , how to make it happen in Mac OS X ( exporting excel to MySQL)